# Number of rows affected after Triggers applied

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have one mysql table on which i created on-after and on-before trigger for insertion. Each tigger update 2 rows respectively. So once i insert a row to the table, altogether 5 rows are updated, even though the response from the DB will be as "1 row is affected". I need to find a way to know the total no of rows got updated, in this case 5.

Comment: Which function you are using to get number of rows affected?

Comment: i am not using any function currently. I'm talking about the mysql reply

Comment: In this case wouldn't it be easy to implement a function that will perform the insertion and the both triggers returning the number of rows modified on the entire process?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that MySQL does not count along when you insert/update rows in a trigger. The best possible solution might be to count the manually inserted/updated rows for yourself, store the value in a variable, get it after the outer query and add the result of ROW_COUNT() to it.

Comment: What you mean by outer query? I'm not able to understand your solution

Comment: You have a query A, which triggers query B and C. B and C insert/update records, and MySQL doesn't count those in ROW_COUNT(). Therefor, you would need to count them in a variable, then after query A finished, add the variable you counted in to the result of ROW_COUNT(), and you should have the correct number of rows affected, including triggers.

Comment: i cant do any manipulation in the database. I'm allowed only to read only

Comment: Then there is no way. You need an information that is not available by means of MySQL itself, and you cannot change the triggers to generate the information. Therefor, you cannot solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is giving one row affected because you are adding one row in table. Mysql reply gives information of row added in that table only. And not giving affected rows by triggers.

Comment: But i need to find the total rows got affected some how. I can use procedures, flags or anthing

Comment: Use : SELECT ROW_COUNT(); After insert query.

Comment: If I am not wrong it is not possible to get number of affected rows by trigger.

Comment: Is that mentioned some where in mysql doc? Actually i'm supposed to write an api for this functionality.

Comment: You have to do it manually if you require it. See same for PostGreSql. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560737/count-number-of-rows-to-be-affected-before-update-in-trigger